# Validar que no se ingresen ni comas ni puntos en un input . React

Tags: reactjs

quisiera pedir ayuda para validar que en un input solo se puedan ingresar numeros enteros.Ni comas ni puntos.Algo asi como al apretar esas dos teclas directamente no pase nada.
Estoy trabajando con React.
Gracias.
eso es lo que intente hasta el momento.

```
 const regex = RegExp("/^([+-]?[1-9]d*|0)$/");
 regex.test(e.target.value) ? e.target.value : null
```

eso en el evento onChange

Comment: Uso de expresiones regulares ?¿ has intentado algo ?

Comment: supuse que por ahi debe estar la respuesta, pero no logre escribir una expresion regular que valide eso. tambien pense mirar si en el evento on change , lo que esta ingresando es un numero con (!isNan) y en ese caso usar el parseInt con ese valor.

Comment: Ya pero, que has intentado. En SO se usa mucho el ver que estas haciendo/intentando. Ahora mismo, yo no puedo suponer que has intentado expresiones regulares, a lo más te mandaría un link para que aprendas a usarlas

Comment: ahi edite la publicacion con lo que intente

Answer (score 0):

```
if (
    e.key === '+' ||
    e.key === '-' ||
    e.key === 'e' ||
    e.key === ',' ||
    e.key === '.' 
) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Ya suponiendo que tu input es `type='number'` podrías poner esta condición